# Renaming all namespaces of current project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces, rename

im working on a project, i started in a namespace, but i want to put everything i made so far into a sub namespace(or deeper) so i can use the 'root' namespace for other projects

exapmle:

```
Namespaces:
Foo
Foo.SubjectA
Foo.SubjectB
```

has to become:

```
Foo.WhatEverIWantHere
Foo.WhatEverIWantHere.SubjectA
Foo.WhatEverIWantHere.SubjectB
```

also I already put all the files into target folders for the namespace renaming in the solution explorer.

I'm looking for something like a tool, or a regex expression for quick-replace. What can you recommend?

Comment: Im looking for something like a tool, or a regex expression for quick-replace

Comment: Visual Studio "Search and replace" can be very effective. Or download a Resharper trial. Resharper has great support for renaming namespaces.

Comment: VS already knows how to do this.  Ensure the project builds cleanly and you have it a good copy in source control.  Right-click the namespace name in the text editor, Refactor + Rename.  Click around some more to get the ropes of the IDE, this is supposed to be discoverable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right Click on the namespace you want to change:

1. Go to [refactor option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgtp7.jpg)
2. Click on Rename
3. Enter new Name and Press Ok